# parsing with XSLT

Tags: parsing, xslt

I am struggling a bit with a solution for the following problem and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

To illustrate the issue I will try and pair it down to its most simple form.  I have the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleData>
    <Data>AA-BRAND1,BB-BRAND1,AA-BRAND2</Data>
</SampleData>
```

and need to produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListOfBrandSales>
    <BrandSales>
        <BrandChannel>AA</BrandChannel>
        <ListOfBrand>
            <Brand>BRAND1</Brand>
            <Brand>BRAND2</Brand>
        </ListOfBrand>
    </BrandSales>
    <BrandSales>
        <BrandChannel>BB</BrandChannel>
            <Brand>BRAND1</Brand>
    </BrandSales>
</ListOfBrandSales>
```

I have been playing with the tokenize and distinct-values functions but am unable to get it.  Seems like I need to nest these functions and not sure if it is possible.  My apologies if the solution is obvious but I am a bit new to XSLT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(/SampleData/Data, ',')" />

<xsl:variable name="channels">
    <xsl:for-each select="$tokens">
        <channel><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '-')"/></channel>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ListOfBrandSales>
        <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($channels/channel)">
            <BrandSales>
                <BrandChannel><xsl:value-of select="."/></BrandChannel>
                   <ListOfBrand>
                       <xsl:for-each select="$tokens[starts-with(., current())]">
                            <Brand><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '-')"/></Brand>
                       </xsl:for-each>
                </ListOfBrand>
            </BrandSales>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ListOfBrandSales>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ListOfBrandSales>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(SampleData/Data, ',')" group-by="substring-before(., '-')">
            <BrandSales>
                <BrandChannel><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></BrandChannel>
                   <ListOfBrand>
                       <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <Brand><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '-')"/></Brand>
                       </xsl:for-each>
                </ListOfBrand>
            </BrandSales>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ListOfBrandSales>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you!  The two examples really help me to understand how to apply the solution in xslt.